# Why is this function not thread safe in golang?

Tags: go, parallel-processing, thread-safety, channel, goroutine

This is the code that I am mentioning:

```
// this is inside some method which has return signature like this: (*Data, error)
mapStore := make(...)
resSlice := make(...)
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
ec := make(chan error)
for keyString, sliceValue := range myMap {
     wg.Add(1)

     keyString := keyString
     sliceValue := sliceValue

     go func() {
          err := func(keyString string, sliceValue []Value, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
                defer wg.Done()
                res, err := process(keyString, sliceValue)
                if err != nil {
                      return errors.Wrapf(err, "wrong")
                }
                if res == nil {
                      return nil
                }
                if res.someData != nil {
                      mapStore[*res.someData] = append(mapStore[*res.someData], res)
                      return nil
                }
                resSlice := append(resSlice, res)
                return nil
               }(keyString, sliceValue, wg)
               if err != nil {
                     ec <- err
                     return
               }
          }()
     }
}
wg.Wait()

select {
case err := <- ec:
      return nil, err
default:
      return resSlice, nil
}
```

I am told that this is not thread safe for some reason but I am not confident as to where. I am thinking its the issue in handling err in `ec` but would appreciate some help!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This snippet is missing a lot of information that would be helpful for debugging. I suspect your problem is when you do this `mapStore[*res.someData]`, where you're modifying a map that you're also iterating over in multiple go-routines.

Comment: The variables  `mapStore` and `resSlice` are modified concurrently.

Comment: Any time you think there is a concurrency issue but you don't know where, [that's what the race detector is for](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't analyzed all of it, but definitely the modification of `mapStore` from multiple goroutines is unsafe:

```
mapStore[*res.someData] = append(mapStore[*res.someData], res)
```

But as a starting point, run this under the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector). It'll find many problems for you.

This is also clearly unsafe:

```
resSlice := append(resSlice, res)
```

But it also doesn't quite do what you think. This creates a new local variable called `resSlice` that shadows the outer one, but it also modifies the outer one (see comments below). Beyond the fact that two things may try to append at the same time and collide, `append` can move the whole slice in memory if it needs to reallocate, so this can cause thread-safety issues even if you put locks around it.

Typically, rather than having each goroutine update some central variable, you want to have each goroutine pass its results back on a channel. Then have the main function collect all the values and update the variables. See [Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) for some examples.

Comment: "but it also modifies the outer one" -> "but it also *might* modify the outer one" - if `append` needs to grow the array, it won't modify the input slice (that's why `append` has a return value).

Comment: @Adrian I was referring to the fact that it would modify the contents and length, which could lead to a collision since this occurs on multiple goroutines. It does that whether it has to reallocate or not. (Am I missing something there?)

Comment: (Ah; you're pointing out that you can wind up with two copies, one that is modified and one that is not. Right?)

Comment: Exactly - behavior of `append` depends entirely on whether it has to expand the array or not. In some cases they'd wind up with two different slices, in some cases they'd wind up with a data race. It's kind of a moot point since the local shadow is almost certainly a bug, just pointing out that `append` doesn't *always* modify the slice it gets as input.